# eclipse c++ nothing to build error

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

so I was trying to build a C++ project, but then I get this error

```
**** Build of configuration Release for project p ****

**** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
Nothing to build for p
```

and I search online for solutions but they're not solving the problem

1. my files are all in lower case
2. my files are properly included in the project, in fact the files were generated from File -> new -> c++ project -> hello world project so they're created by eclipse...

and the code is just the eclipse hello world code...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

1. The compiler is installed properly...I got mingw on C:\mingw and the project's includes folder contain all these files properly...

does anyone know what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Had this exact same problem today, but luckily I found a video which sorted it out for me. Seems we weren't properly installing MinGW.

Check this out:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2cfc9ERkpk

Answer (score 0):

You should add "msys" path (C:\MinGW\msys\1.0) to tour project along with MinGW path (C:\MinGW\bin). Then build goes fine.