# Nothing to build: Eclipse Issues for C++

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have some experience with Java and Eclipse, but I'm new to C++, and trying to teach myself. I apologize if this is a simple question, or one that has already been asked (though I looked around for a while.) I'm on a Windows 8.

I'm trying to make a sorted linked list (which is relatively unimportant.) I get:

```
Info: Nothing to build for Working.
```

Here's my code:

```
/*
*  SortedList class
*/
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include "SortedList.h"

using namespace std;

//the ListNode Structure
struct ListNode {
    string data;
    ListNode *next;
};

//the head of the linked list and the pointer nodes
ListNode head;
ListNode *prev, *current;

// insert a string into the list in alphabetical order
//now adds a string to the list and counts the size of the list
int Insert(string s){
//make the new node
ListNode temp;
temp.data = s;
//the node to traverse the list
prev = &head;
current = head.next;
int c = 0;
//traverse the list, then insert the string
while(current != NULL){
    prev = current;
    current = current->next;
    c++;
}

//insert temp into the list
temp.next = prev->next;
prev->next = &temp;

return c;
}

//Return the number of times a given string occurs in the list.
int Lookup(string s){
return 0;
}

//prints the elements of the list to ostream
void Print(ostream &output){
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
cout << Insert("a") << endl;
cout << Insert("b") << endl;
cout << Insert("d") << endl;
}
```

And here's my header:

```
using namespace std;

#ifndef SORTEDLIST_H_
#define SORTEDLIST_H_

class SortedList {
  public:
    // constructor
    SortedList();
    // modifiers
    int Insert(string s);
    // other operations
    int Lookup(string s) const;
    void Print(ostream &output) const;

  private:
    struct ListNode {
       string data;
       ListNode *next;
    };
    // pointer to the first node of the list
    ListNode head;
    ListNode *prev, *current;
};
#endif /* SORTEDLIST_H_ */
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to setup a C++ project in CDT?

Comment: problem has nothing to do with the code. you have some problem with your build environment. First google hit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504446/eclipse-c-nothing-to-build-error

Comment: Does simple "Hello, World" program compile and run in your environment?

Comment: I've run other programs, yes, but nothing using classes so far. I do not know how to set up a CDT-- I'm an absolute beginner. I'll check out that other link, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use std::deque (in header deque)? It probably has all the functionality you are seeking, it is fully tested and optimised. If you need a deque with a bit more of functionality, create a class that inherit from it and add the functions you need. Have a look to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/containe and pick up the container that best suits your needs.

As a general advise, if something you need is already available in some good and stable library (STL, boost, GSL, Armadillo or similar), much better use it rather than to write+debug+optimise it yourself from scratch. As a general advise, focus your efforts on the code that is unique to your application, and reuse what has already be done (BUT only if it has been well tested, do not use crappy half cooked libraries).

Comment: the OP said that he/she is learning C++, so it might be just an exercise, that's how you learn. Your answer doesn't have anything to do with the question.