# Eclipse C++ "Nothing to build" error

Tags: c++, eclipse, build

I've been having a "nothing to build error" working with C++ in Eclipse. I have been unable to even get a simple "hello world" program, in a project named "hw," to run:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
return 0;
}
```

What is this "nothing to build" error? What does it mean? Why is it occurring? How do I fix it? I have checked what few leads I could find both here and elsewhere, but have thus far found nothing to help.

Comment: Are you sure the source file(.cpp) is in the Project `hw`?

Comment: And is the project selected as the Active Project ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [eclipse c++ nothing to build error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504446/eclipse-c-nothing-to-build-error)

Answer (score 6):

You can check if the project properties are ok. If you change the source code location and do not refresh this project property, probably the compiler will not find it. You can check this as follows:

Right click on Project folder -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Source Location (just in case)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.  I finally resolved everything by carefully following the directions for installing MinGW which require that you install the C and C++ compilers and MSYS basic syste, and MinGW developer toolk packages.  Also make sure that C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin are added to your Path system variables. Insuring all of these did the trick for me.

Comment: Adding "C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin" to my path fixed the problem for me! It didn't appear to at first... I had to wait a while and try again but somehow the issue is resolved.

Comment: I agree, your path setting need to be setup that will point to the MinGW and msys directories.  Once you have the settings setup; restart eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason is the name of the source file. If you forget to give it a .cpp postfix it will generate this error.
Good luck!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @ruffp Actually, It does (attempt to) answer the question.

Comment: I was rename source file extension **.CXX** to **.cxx** and error disappears.

Answer (score 1):

enter to Project-> Properties -> Project Natures and **add** C Nature (should be two enters of "C nature")

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, couldn't get anything to build.  I had MinGW installed in the default directory and had to modify my path settings as well.  Instructions on changing your path variable can be found http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer was directed at a C++ application but the problem also manifests itself if you import a project into a C project that has files that have an upper case trailing C in the filename.  For example if any files exist as FileName.C the above error will be printed.

Simply changing all the files so that they have a lower case 'c' will fix the problem.   That is FileName.C becomes FileName.c.   This has caught me twice now!

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I think that there are a few words that cannot be used in file names.

I installed Eclipse Mars and MinGW on Windows 7, then opened eclipse to run the classic "Hello World" program and it successfully built, and ran.

So, I created new project "OutPutText" and ran the same code as the "Hello World" and I got the “Nothing to build” error.

Then I myself tried some stupid permutation and combinations of project name. I found out that if I add the word "text" to the name of the file the error comes back and if I don't it runs fine!

I tested even more and found that this particular name "OutPuttingText" is causing the problem but not "OutPut Text" or "OutPutting Text" or "OutPut" as file names.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your virus protection is disabled before installing the compiler minGW. This is what was causing my identical problem. The virus protection can prevent some dll files from being installed and this error won't be flagged up which is what caused my problems. 
After installing minGW (without virus protection), re-install eclipse (I used mars2) and it worked fine.

Prior to this I had searched every similar thread but nothing worked. 
Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I don't think you answer the question as posed.   You point to no authority when suggesting that anti-virus software should be removed.

Comment: "Why is it occuring?"- no dll's . "How to fix it" - disable virus protection. I think I answered 2 of the questions posed. Who's authority do you want? It worked for me , it 'may' work for someone else, I thought that was the point

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem where the project file was copied from another project;
problem in my case was that the source path was having a different case (Src instead of src) on a windows system